# Quartus II Error (18994): configuration scheme "passive serial" is not valid for the device

Tags: quartus

I'm trying to synthesize a System Verilog RTL design to a Stratix 10 device using quartus II v.17 but keep getting the following error.

> Info (12627): Pin ~ALTERA_MSEL0~ is reserved at location AY8
>
> Info (12627): Pin ~ALTERA_MSEL1~ is reserved at location AY13
>
> Info (12627): Pin ~ALTERA_MSEL2~ is reserved at location AR14
>
> Error (18994): configuration scheme "passive serial" is not valid for the device

All my top-level ports have been assigned VIRTUAL_PIN ON as this is just a small part of a larger design and I just want to see if it synthesizes. The error occurs for all Stratix 10 devices. The MSEL# pin locations vary per device.

What is causing the error and how do I fix it? How do I tell Quartus II not to use "Passive Serial"?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The following solution was received on the Altera Forums.

go to Asigments-> Device -> Device and Pin options -> Configuration to change configuration mode. Also you can try to play with settings in Asigments-> Device -> Device and Pin options -> Dual-Purpose Pins section

The tcl commands are

> set_global_assignment -name STRATIXV_CONFIGURATION_SCHEME "ACTIVE SERIAL X1"

It fixed the problem.